# User Profile Synchronization Service won't start String not recognized as DateTime

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I am currently using Sharepoint 2013 on premises.
User Profile Synchronization Service won't start with the following error:

```
> UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure ILM, will
> attempt during next rerun. Exception:
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an
> error deserializing the object . String was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a
> valid DateTime.      at System.DateTime.Parse(String s,
> IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Utilities.DateTimeSerializer.ReadCoordinatedUniversalTimeStringIntoCoordinatedUniversalDateTime(String
> input)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.Resource.ResourceSerializer.ProcessElement(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader, Boolean& readerAdvanced)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.Resource.ResourceSerializer.ProcessElements(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.Resource.ResourceSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)      at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
> reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
> dataContractResolver)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
> reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
> dataContractResolver)      at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.Resource.Deserialize(XmlReader
> reader, LocaleAwareClientHelper localePreferences)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.Client.Resource..ctor(UniqueIdentifier
> identifier, CultureInfo locale, Nullable`1 resourceTime,
> ContextualSecurityToken securityToken, Boolean includePermissionHints,
> TimeZoneInfo resourceTimeZone)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManager..ctor(UniqueIdentifier
> resourceIdentifier, CultureInfo locale, Nullable`1 resourceTime,
> ContextualSecurityToken securityToken, Boolean includePermissionHints,
> TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone)      at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManager..ctor(UniqueIdentifier
> resourceIdentifier, CultureInfo locale, Nullable`1 resourceTime,
> ContextualSecurityToken securityToken, Boolean includePermissionHints)
> at
> Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManager..ctor(UniqueIdentifier
> resourceIdentifier, CultureInfo locale, Boolean
> includePermissionHints)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.UpdateFIMUser(SchemaManager
> schemaManager, String userName, String accountName, String domain,
> Byte[] userSid)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIISAdminsList(Hashtable
> htPermittedUsers)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupProfileSynchronizationEnginePermissions()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance
> profileSyncInstance).
```

The farm administrator user has replication permits. 
I have cleared Cache Config.
The Sharepoint web server has the same regional as the AD server.
What could be wrong?

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 if you programatically insert a date time in any other format than an ISO8601 valid format it will throw an Argument Exception complaining about the date format.

Comment: Ok, but I am using SharePoint 2013. To add I didn't do any programming.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Regional Settings of the Domain User that is running SharePoint Timer Service is the same as Language ID of the SharePoint Installation.
You can check regional settings for that user opening PS with "run-as" the user you want to check and executing Get-WinSystemLocale on Windows Server 2012 or Get-Culture on Windows server 2008 R2.

it should return this

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1053             sv-SE            Swedish (Sweden)
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately the Language of the user is the same as the installation

Comment: Could this link be of help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e7823656-2c82-4af2-b429-99cc75815097/profile-synchronization-problem?forum=sharepointadminprevious It is someone having the same issues with Date fields based on their formatting?

Comment: I recommend using this format 2014-07-31T15:00:00Z . Working on some other things through SharePoint webservices and this format is always accepted it is what SharePoint is working with behind the UI. Should mention that my Regional settings are Japanese on a US English server.